# Comparing SHA256 Output in Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, hash

This question might probably be a duplicate. But so far I haven't seen any response that could solve mine issue.
I have this piece of Java code doing encryption with `SHA-256`:

```
public static String hashIt(String msg, String key) {

    MessageDigest m = null;
    String hashText = null;
    byte[] actualKeyBytes =  TripleDES.hexStringToBytes(key);
    try {
        m = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        m.update(actualKeyBytes, 0, actualKeyBytes.length);
        try {
            m.update(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, msg.length());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

        }
        hashText = TripleDES.bytesToHexString( m.digest() ); //new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {

    }
    return hashText;
}
```

Using `d38a5cd5` as key with `"ewo10kalavanda"` as the string to hash.

```
Utils.hashIt("ewo10kalavanda", "d38a5cd5");
```

I have the following output:

```
fc87c73012e11de3a57faabe4d852ce89ec3337504531c16
```

Using the same `SHA256` in `PHP`

```
hash_hmac('SHA256', "ewo10kalavanda", "d38a5cd5", $raw=false)
```

The output is `1839412f79b9e33c2f810650f79f23f46173792f885dd8d8c9633675e28e792f` which does not match that of Java.

Is there anything done wrong here? Been on this for some hours now.

Comment: line `m.update(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, msg.length());` buggy.

Comment: @glee8e why do you think it is buggy?

Comment: Plz see my anwser below.

Comment: It seems you really want a HMAC in both PHP and Java, not a do-it-yourself implementation. See [Hash-based message authentication code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [other answer from glee8e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071509/589259) should have got you a long way. But just to be sure, here is how to generate the output:

```
$k = hex2bin("d38a5cd5");
$m = "ewo10kalavanda";
$in = $k.$m;
$h = hash ("SHA256", $in);
print $h;
```

It would be a bit better to first encode to UTF-8, but I haven't got the right module installed:

```
$m = mb_convert_encoding("ewo10kalavanda", "UTF-8");
```

for the test sting this of course doesn't matter as long as the platform encoding is compatible with UTF-8 for the input characters.

---

That's however half of the answer though: there is a reason why HMAC was defined, and the major reason is that hash functions on their own are not that secure for keyed hash or Message Authentication Code (MAC). So the use of HMAC as in the PHP function should be preferred.

Comment: Waoh!! That worked perfectly and got the same hashed value output with Java. Thanks a lot. Two major points: The Hex2bin of the key and concatenation of key and password. Also using `HASH` instead of `HASH_MAC` . Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code you used HMAC which is more than just hashing the string obtained by joining key and the message body. I found a diagram from Wikipedia which explains how HMAC-SHA1 works:

[image: HMAC-SHA1 diagram]

I did manage to get a working version in Java:

```
public static String hashIt(String msg, String key) {
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, HMAC_SHA256);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256);
        mac.init(spec);
        return TripleDES.bytesToHexString(mac.doFinal(msg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

---

I still think there is something wrong with `msg.length()`. If you ever hash a two byte character it will be buggy. I tested it and it's different. For example try use your previous code to hash `111111錒`(message) and `1111`(key) and then use my previously suggested code to hash the same string. Your code output `81e385eb2bf89f7494a4b0927a4f5d4105450eb4a21152d53d52ddb9c08ed0e1` and my code output `ef7f82833c865ef4d6089ba7dfbec8ad4f05b58e3fd77ca242c5fd7e7757d8b4`.

<sub>That chinese character is intended. It shows how the OP's code fails with two byte characters. DO NOT REMOVE.</sub>

Comment: Your answer is same as what I did here `byte[] actualKeyBytes =  TripleDES.hexStringToBytes(key);`